# Flutter: theme is not applied when installed from google console/play

Tags: flutter, google-play

got specific questions for Flutter when deployed in Google Play. Why is it that when an app is installed from Google Play (Flutter + CodeMagic), it loses its theme and use the default blue theme I think.

When we build the APK manually and install in simulator or actual device (android), the theme is applied.

Comment: Was the APK you built manually a release build?

Comment: yes release build

Comment: Thats intresting. My first guess would have been something gets thrown out during minifying. Do you use any product flavor config, that might change themes?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the playstore apk? It might have some useful logs.